# can i use wget to download specific files from a url/directory?

Tags: wget

specifying the filename works:

```
wget http://172.21.200.37/~username/dir_name/filename.csv
```

But what I want is specific files that begin with `H_` like below, but i can't get this to work

```
wget http://172.21.200.37/~username/dir_name/H_*.csv
```

I get the following:

```
Warning: wildcards not supported in HTTP.
--2014-05-08 10:31:20--  http://172.21.200.37/~username/dir_name/H_*.csv
Connecting to 172.21.200.37:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2014-05-08 10:31:20 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

Can I do this with wget or do I need another command?

Comment: try ftp if available, or ssh with rsync, or scp

Answer (score 0):

This could only work if the web server somehow offers a list of URLs that are valid in the `/dir_name/` directory. The server *might* be configured to generate a human readable index if you request `wget http://172.21.200.37/~username/dir_name/` but there is no requirement for it to do so.

If you do get such a list of files, you would need to call `wget` for each file starting with `H_` in turn.

Comment: this might be the best option thus far, just need to overwrite the existing files in the directory, or else I delete them before doing the wget